# Re-rendering a hidden element

Tags: meteor

I am creating a meteor app that has a list of posts visible on the left half of the page and a hidden display container on the right. The user clicks on the post title, and display container becomes on the right side of the page and shows the full post. Now, the container that displays the full post is initially hidden and simply has its elements filled with handlebar expressions. If you click on another post, the same display container stays open, but simply has its contents changed.

Clicking on post

```
Template.postsList.events({
   'click .post': function (e, template) {
       e.preventDefault();
       Session.set('selectedPost', this._id);
   }
});
```

Example handlebar expression

```
Template.postDisplay.title = function () {
   return Posts.findOne(Session.get('selectedPost')).title
}
```

Everything is working fine and well, except the reactive nature of the display container. If something in the database changes (whether it be an added comment, change in the title, etc) the display becomes hidden again and I have to re-click the post. The postsList template has all their values updated normally and seamlessly without any blink or anything.

Is there a way to have the display container's values update while keeping it from being hidden?

This is how I've been displaying the container. Just regular show and hide.

On document load

```
$('#post-display-container').hide();
```

On element click

```
 $('.title').click(function () {
    $('#post-display-container').show()
 });
```

Example of the postDisplay template. I didn't do the whole thing, of course.

```
<template name="postDisplay">
   {{#each posts}}
   <h3 class='title'>{{title}}</h3>
   <p class='body'>{{body}}</p>
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

Template helper

```
Template.postDisplay.helpers({
     posts: function () {
         return Posts.find(Session.get('selectedPost'));
     }
})
```

Comment: This should be easy. There's probably an error in how you display the container. Could you show the code you use to make it visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Meteor docs, in the [session.equal](http://docs.meteor.com/#session_equals) you can see what to do when you click the desired post.

Adding the class selected to your post on the left would give a clue what post is current selected.

And in the right you only show the current selected post based on your session as well. Don't try to show a post when clicking. Think about put some class that make that post appears.

Just to be clear, you have to change your post display to look similar to that below so when re-rendering the class would still be there and your post(on the right) would still be showing. By the way, remove the .hide() when the page loads too and change the behavior when clicking the post to change the session to the new current selected post.

```
<template name="postItem">
  <div class="{{postClass}}">{{title}}</div>
</template>

Template.postItem.postClass = function() {
   return Session.equals("selectedPost", this._id) ?
      "selected" : "";
};
```

Comment: When a user first arrives on the page, the right side isn't blank (site branding, other things). When a user clicks a post, that stuff is just covered up. Will removing the hide affect this?

Comment: @CassioSCabral "you have to change your post display to look similar to that below so when re-rendering the class would still be there and your post(on the right) would still be showing" Can you explain this? I'm not sure I get you.

Comment: In your template post display you need a div that surround the post, which will have a possible "selected" class that will come from the helper postClass function. The selected class means the post has display: block, which is equivalent to call .show() on that element. When the post is clicked it would alter current selected post on the session and re-render automatically showing the right post. If none post is selected you can show something else on the right side.